# SP2016 Document Set files disappear when marked complete or archived

Tags: 2016, document-set, bug

I'm having an issue with one of my site's library that uses Document Set. I have SharePoint 2016 (I know, I know - out of my control my company doesn't want to upgrade yet) and I'm running to an issue that I can't find a real solution everywhere I've looked.

The Document Set is being used for process tracking tied to "Steps" which are Look-ups. All the steps behave as intended when the user select the appropriate step to add the files they need, and then when they are done they assign it the to next step. When the user (or me) select the final step, the files disappear. They don't get deleted, I checked, they just disappear.

After doing some testing I found out that for whatever reason SP doesn't like the step to be name "complete," "completed," "archived," or anything else that resembles that. The second I rename the final step to something else, all the files become visible again. I don't have any filters affecting the view or anything; the only thing I have is groupings by "Step," but nothing else affecting the page.

Please let me know if you know of a solution or something else I can try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default view on the library cannot contain any filters. When you click into a Document Set, it drills down using the default view which adds filters to only show items not marked as completed or archived.

Comment: That was it! I changed the default view and now it's working fine. It's crazy how it will change views when drilling down into the document set. Thanks!